# Problem while creating 2D array dynamically in C++. Here is the code. It dosen't work for some specific conditions

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array

In my following code i am taking input (int) rows and cols form the user and creating a 2d array. After taking the input i am printing the same 2d array.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int rows,cols;
    cin>>rows>>cols;
    int **matrix=new int*[cols];
    for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        matrix[j]=new int[rows] ;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<cols;k++)
        {
            cin>>matrix[j][k];
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<cols;k++)
        {
            cout<<matrix[j][k]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly in 2 cases:

```
1st. when input rows and cols are equal.
2nd. when cols>rows.
```

`It dosent work for the case in which rows>cols.` If you don't trust me, run it and check. I don't know where i am going wrong. Compiler is also not giving any errors. Please help!!

Comment: You swap cols and rows after the first loop (considering the first loop is right, we can't guess your design)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong use of `rows` and `cols`. In places where you need rows you use cols sometimes, and vice versa. Full corrected code:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZDNboMwEITvfopVegHSSm1JesHxiyAOlnGQ@VkjbJRKFc9OWSjQ9NZDVvJl9tPMrFXbvqhaYjGOTwZV3eeaG@t8p2UjWO8MFoCy0a6VSoPzecIMemikwSBkXwymIaGzN/esbO2SWVIGhSBNiF0kLooa6TvzeUF9IyFKicoW4Gq7gKDy8pqUnBZJeTyG826JolkM0jJbPVKKyGDxGP7htFLVRFV8Llqt1D253bSFp9VP6T30gdG295z/zub8AIe/BXZUY16v/zGwcYzhnb1NL4YTO8PHNw)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int rows,cols;
    cin>>rows>>cols;
    int **matrix=new int*[rows];
    for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
    {
        matrix[j]=new int[cols] ;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<cols;k++)
        {
            cin>>matrix[j][k];
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<rows;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<cols;k++)
        {
            cout<<matrix[j][k]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Input:

```
3 2

1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Output:

```
1 2 
3 4 
5 6
```

Comment: Note that this changes the memory layout to row-major.  Depending on the context and what matrix operations will be most common, column-major can potentially be more cache friendly.  (Though OP probably doesn't care in this case.)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to decide whether the first subscript  referred to the row or the column, and then you changed your mind halfway through the code. If it’s a row-major array then you’re allocating it wrong; if it’s column-major then you’re filling it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate first by `cols`, then by `rows`.  This means your matrix is "column major".  But then in your second and third loop you use the *row* `j` as the primary index, followed by the *column* `k` as the secondary index.  If `rows != cols`, you will end up walking off the end of one of the arrays, invoking Undefined Behavior.

Because your matrix is column major, you have to index first by the column number, *then* by the row number.  For example:

```
for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
{
    for(int k=0;k<rows;k++)
    {
        cin>>matrix[j][k];
    }
}
```